# c# datasource to memory and memory to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, database, service, datasource

I have a requirement to

1. Save a datasource from a database query to memory so i can loop
   through and update some of the items in memory.
2. I also need to be able to save the items in memory (from the result of item 1 above)
   to an `xml` file on the hard drive.
3. Finally i need to be able to load the `xml` file into memory.

Could anyone point me the easiest method of doing this. This is all done in a windows service.

```
FAItemsUnderControl fItemsUnderControl = new FAItemsUnderControl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"]);

//Note the line below is for binding to a gridview which is incorrect in my requirement but illustrates the idea

GridViewItemsUnderControlReport.DataSource = fItemsUnderControl.getItemsUnderControl("systemidtbd", "ALL");
```

Comment: 1. `fItemsUnderControl` is already in memory, 2 and 3 you can use `System.Xml.Serialization`

Comment: i have tried to map the result to a list of objects but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to declare the same list of objects on my service side

```
// Get items to Control into running memory
                FAItemsUnderControl fItemsUnderControl = new FAItemsUnderControl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"]);
                MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl = fItemsUnderControl.getItemsUnderControl(MyGlobals.System_ID, "ALL").ToList<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult>();
```